# Cannot edit data directly in Firebase console

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Not sure if this is intentional on the part of Firebase or not but I can't edit any of values in my Firebase Realtime Database console despite changing both read and write rules to `"true"`. At the moment the only way I can change the value of a given key is to delete the key and create it again with the new value. Is this normal? I am almost sure I was able to do it before. If there is something else I need to do or can try I'd be grateful to know. Thanks!

Comment: *firebaser here* That doesn't sound normal. I just quickly tested and can change values in the Firebase Console for one of my projects fine. Do you get any error messages in the JavaScript console? If not, can you show a screenshot of your browser and maybe share some details to help me reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just on the off chance, I relaunched the browser and lo-and-behold it fixed it! So a bit of a false alarm. Thanks for the response all the same!

Comment: Good to hear Mikey! Voting to close...